# Copying bytes of array of uint_32 to unsigned char

Tags: c

I am trying to copy the bytes of state to charstate using memcpy

```
uint32_t state[3] = {0x00000300, 0x00001100, 0x00022200};
unsigned char charstate[1420];
memcpy(charstate, (unsigned char *)state, sizeof(uint32_t)*3);
printf("charstate: %s", charstate);
```

But the printf sentence does not return anything. Could you help me to copy this state array to charstate, please?

Comment: `%s` is for a string. Do you really think the value in `charstate` is a valid string? It looks more like binary data. A string stops at the first NUL character. The value of a NUL character is `0`.

Comment: to expand on what @kaylum is saying, you would want to loop through all the characters and then print each one with `%x` which is hex annotation. So you could do `for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(charstate); ++i){ printf("charstate at %i: %x",i, charstate[i]); }`

Comment: Note: `(unsigned char *)` cast not needed in `memcpy(charstate, (unsigned char *)state, sizeof(uint32_t)*3);`

Comment: @Andy Please consider making an answer. Or maybe allow me to complete mine by adding your proposed solution, with credit to you of course.

Comment: @kaylum My answer overlaps with your comment of course. I think I contribute additional insight however. Please let me know if you object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need help with the copying, you already succeeded.
The problem that you `printf()` does not output anything is caused by the format specifier `"%s"` printing only the characters it finds **before** the first 0 valued one.
Compare https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Looking at the data you copy, the first 0 value is found either in 0x000003**00** or in 0x**00**000300, depending on the applicable endianess in your environment.
I.e. the very first value which `printf("%s",...)` encounters already is 0. It hence stops before outputting anything.

If the first value would not happen to be 0, you would probably not get expected output either. You would only get output at all for printable characters, which seem to be kind of rate in your data and that would probably not be what you expect either.

You probably want a hex representation of the data and Andy has proposed a way for that in the comments.